# Acceleration value if coulomb's force equals to 0?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, acceleration

If i have a point in an electric field where the coulmb's force is equal to 0 does this mean that the acceleration and the velocity of the charge q in the mentioned point are also equal to 0?

In this case the electric field is not constant in every point the coulomb's force is different, in other words the charge q is not in an plate capacitor.

Comment: Zero force results in zero acceleration and velocity not changing but not necessarily zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the electric force is the only force applicable in the situation and it is zero, then using Newton's Second Law we know that the acceleration is equal to zero in that point. Since the acceleration is equal to zero the velocity is constant (not necessarily zero)